# Spring Boot 3 working on embedded Tomcat, but not on external Tomcat

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, tomcat

I created a spring boot 3.0.0 app and when i run it on my IDE (intelliJ) it works perfectly, but when i try to deploy it to an external tomcat (tomcat version 10.1.7) it doesn't work.

When i run it on my IDE and access localhost:8080/projeto it shows me the page its supposed to show and i can navigate from there on to the other pages and do the things the webapp is meant to do. But when i access localhost:8080/projeto after running an external tomcat that has my app in a folder named "projeto" inside the webapps folder, i get the error:

"HTTP Status 404 – Not Found.
Type Status Report.
Message The requested resource [/projeto/] is not available
Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
Apache Tomcat/10.1.7"

the java -version being used in both cases is 19.0.1.

This is my pom.xml currently:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<packaging>war</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>TestSecurity</groupId>
<artifactId>Projeto</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Projeto</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>projeto</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

I've tried changing the tomcat version to different versions but i feel that the version 10.1.7 should work with this webapp, even though so far i've had no success with it.

EDIT:
I've added this dependency to the pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

and created this file logback.xml inside the resources folder:

```
<configuration>
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>${catalina.base}/logs/projetologs.log</file>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</root>
</configuration>
```

I did this in an attempt to get logs of the error and finding out what's going on but the projetologs.log file created inside the logs folder in tomcat is created empty and no entries are added after trying to run the app and accessing localhost:8080/projeto

This is the controller for "/":

```
    import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @GetMapping(value = "/")
    public ModelAndView homePage() {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("index");

        if (SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal() != "anonymousUser") {

            User user = (User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

            mav.addObject("username", user.getUsername());
        }

        return mav;
    }

}
```

I also have this line in my application.properties to set the app's context path to /projeto

```
server.servlet.context-path=/projeto
```

---

following @xerx593 's suggestion i made a minimal app which had the same Java, spring boot and tomcat versions and when i tried to deploy it to the tomcat i got the same 404 error.

The minimal app is literally just this controller:

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping ("/")
    public String home(){
        return "HOME page";
    }

    @GetMapping ("/admin")
    public String admin(){
        return "ADMIN page";
    }

    @GetMapping ("/user")
    public String user(){
        return "USER page";
    }
}
```

this pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<packaging>war</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>groupz</groupId>
<artifactId>artifactz</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>namez</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>19</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>artifactz</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

and this application.properties:

```
server.servlet.context-path=/artifactz
```

It seems like whatever is cause the error for the bigger app is also happening here with this minimal app. Probably a version incompatibility but spring boot 3+ is supposed to be compatible with tomcat 10.1.7

Comment: Share the full error trace.

Comment: What have you deployed to tomcat? The created jar file or have you changed to create a war file?

Comment: I guess that you get a projecto.war file that you deploy as-is (not as ROOT) and you have an endpoint that is /projeto - by default tomcat will add the context path as the war filename (but not the embedded in spring boot) so I would guess that the correct path is `http://localhost:8080/projeto/projeto`

Comment: @AjayKumar i dont have one, it simply does not run in the tomcat server and i cant get it to create logs.

Comment: i deployed a war file created with mvn package @khmarbaise

Comment: @grekier thanks for the suggestion but i tried "http://localhost:8080/projeto/projeto" and i get the same error 404.
Also, i've deployed a project that is in many ways VERY similar to this one (major difference was the spring boot version 2.7.3 instead of 3.0.0, and tomcat 9.0.65 instead of 10.1.7) and it worked with the same context path as in the IDE.

Comment: 1. why/what for do you have `tomcat-embed-jasper` as dependency? (2. maria/mysql is ambiguous) 3. what says catalina.out/logs: any "spring boot banner" in sight?

Comment: @xerx593 1. i added "tomcat-embed-jasper" as dependency because for some reason i cant understand when i dont have it i get an error saying that the filterChain required an HttpSecurity bean that could not be found. Adding "tomcat-embed-jasper" removes the error, but im not sure how. 2. i've used these dependencies combined before on opther versions of spring boot and it worked. 3. no banner in sight, it only says it started the servlet and deployed app to /projeto in the console after starting the startup.bat. I cant get it to create logs. I feel like it's a compatibility issue with versions

Comment: ok, thank you! (consider (in advance/addtitionally to commenting) to [edit] your post, to add relevant info) 1. is strange/smelly, please also investigate/track. (for now can live with 2.;) 3. is frustrating and should be investigated/fixed priorized. ..try to deploy a simple as possible application to tomcat(which also runs in ide) ..start with a spring-starter#type=war

Comment: Try this: http://localhost:8080/Projeto  Capital P

Comment: @AjayKumar tried with capital P but no luck. Thank you for the suggestion

Comment: How is deployed in Tomcat?

Comment: @grekier i extracted the war file (which contains the WEB-INF, org and META-INF folders) to a folder named projeto inside the webapps folder of the tomcat. So the app is inside the projeto folder, which is inside the webapps folder in the tomcat folder.

Comment: Then all your endpoints should have the `/projeto` context path in addition to the endpoint definition in your project. Can you show the RestController code?

Comment: @grekier Yes, and they do. But i have an endpoint "/" wich is accessible at "localhost:8080/projeto". I also have this: "server.servlet.context-path=/projeto" in my application.properties so that all endpoints have the /projeto context path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed.

There were 2 things i needed to change to make it work.
First i had to add to the main class "extends SpringBootServletInitializer" and Override the configure method, both of these i thought i had done but apparently totally forgot.

Even after adding those changes it still didn't work, but after changing the tomcat version from 10.1.7 to 10.0.2 it started working for some reason. I still think 10.1.7 should be compatible. But at least its running now.

Thank you to everyone who helped.